# script not redirecting when query fails

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following lines of code

```
if(isset($_GET['course_id'])) {
    $data_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['course_id']);
    $subscriptionVerification = "SELECT `user_id`, `course_id` FROM subscriptions WHERE `user_id` = '".$user_id."' and `course_id`='".$data_id."'";
    $subscriptionResult = mysql_query($subscriptionVerification);
    if(!mysql_num_rows($subscriptionResult)===1)
     {
         header("location:login.php");
         die(); // sends user to the login page if their userID and subscription code do not match the page they are trying to retrieve
     }            
}
```

the problem is that when i get the course_id from chapters.php?course_id=1234 and if that id doesnt exist in the mysql db, it still loads the page instead of redirecting.

if I write `if(mysql_num_rows($subscriptionResult)===1)` without the `!` then it does work and it directs all traffic (including the correct course ids) over.

I'm wondering if there's something I'm doing wrong. I've tried the following two variations as well
`if(!$subscriptionResult)` and `if($subscriptionResult===FALSE)` but neither have worked.

the purpose of this is to avoid having people try to manually put in course_id (especially ones that don't exist) and load the page with content in it.

Comment: if adding a `!` makes it work, then you've simply got a query that returns no results, meaning the result has 0 rows, and mysql_num_rows() is returning a 0. The alternative is that the query utterly fails due to errors, you get a boolean false back, and since you have no error handling at all, that boolean false will be `!`-notted into a true-ish value.

Comment: what about just using if(mysql_num_rows($subscriptionResult)!=1)?  Have you tried that yet?

Comment: @MarcB that did solve it. I removed the `!` and made it `===0` which actually makes sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
if(!$subscriptionResult || mysql_num_rows($subscriptionResult)!==1)
```

This will redirect if the result is empty, or if the number of rows is not 1.

I'd also strongly recommend switching from the deprecated mysql_* queries to PDO or mysqli.